# Form Values from Model Not Updating in View After Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I believe I'm missing something quite trivial here, but I'm not spotting it. I have a `Post` method, which modifies a Model property. I then want that model property to reflect the new property value. So here are the pieces:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeModel model)
    {

        ModelState.Clear(); //Didn't help
        model.MyValue = "Hello this is a different value";

        return View(model);

    }
```

Model:

```
public class HomeModel
{
    [Display(Name = "My Message")]
    public string MyValue { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
@model MyApp.Models.HomeModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "My MVC App";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
      {
         <h5>Hello</h5> 
         <input id="SendMessage" type="submit" value="Send Message"/> 
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyValue)
      }

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I debug the controller I can see the updated model, but my `LabelFor` always has the `Display` attribute as opposed to the value I provided of `"Hello this is a different value"`. What am I missing here that this label is not updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Html.LabelFor` displays your property name (or the name defined in your `DisplayAttribute`), whereas `@Html.DisplayFor` displays your property content. If your want `"Hello this is a different value"` displays, replace `@Html.LabelFor` by `@Html.DisplayFor`

Comment: I knew it was something simple. :/ Thank you this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

The html helper look at the `ModelState` when binding their values and then in the model.

So if you intend to modify any of the POSTed values inside your controller action make sure you remove them from the model state first:

```
 ModelState.Remove("PropertyName");
```

Read this [MVC 3 - Html.EditorFor seems to cache old values after $.ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414351/mvc-3-html-editorfor-seems-to-cache-old-values-after-ajax-call/7449628#7449628)

Answer (score 1):

That's the purpose of `LabelFor`, display the property name. Either use `EditorFor` or just access the model property directly inside a `label` tag it to your view

```
     <h5>Hello</h5> 
     <input id="SendMessage" type="submit" value="Send Message"/> 
     <label>@Model.MyValue</label>
```