# Displaying a collection from data in ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on refactoring a MVC project to clean up the controllers by using action filters to perform PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) when `ModelState` is not valid, and storing `ModelState` in `TempData` during the redirect.

I have a view model that looks something like this:

```
public class GroupMember
{
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  public bool SendNotifications { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  // ...
  public List<GroupMember> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Controller actions:

```
[HttpGet]
[ImportModelState]
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model = new Group();
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateModelState]
public ActionResult Create(
  [Bind(Exclude = "Id")]
  Group model)
{
  // call service to save
  // ...
}
```

The problem I'm having is with getting the collection `Group.Members` to display correctly after a redirect.  `ModelState` is loaded 100% correctly, and works fine for the properties like `Group.Name`, where the called to `Html.EditorFor(...)` loads the data from `ModelState` instead of using the (empty) model.

I have an editor template for `GroupMember` (which works fine in all but the redirect scenario) and am displaying the collection using `Html.EditorFor(model => model.Members)`, but apparently MVC does *not* check `ModelState` in this case, so it always displays an empty list.

Is there a clean way to fix this?  I think I should be able to store the number of members in a hidden field and check by hand to see if it has a value in `ModelState`, but that seems like a clumsy workaround.

Edit:
The workaround I've come up with is to add a property `NumMembers` to `Group`, and insert the following into the Razor view:

```
@{
  ModelState state;
  var numMembers = ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue("NumMembers", out state)
    ? int.Parse(state.Value.AttemptedValue)
    : Model.Members.Count;

  if (numMembers != Model.Members.Count)
  {
    Model.Members = Enumerable.Repeat(new GroupMember(), numMembers).ToList();
  }
}
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NumMembers)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Members)
```

My javascript code which fixes the item indices for proper model binding updates the NumMembers hidden field before a post.  Still hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: are you using it correctly? http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/      http://www.pearson-and-steel.co.uk/how-to-use-the-html-editorfor-method/

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv those articles have literally nothing to do with my question

Comment: they both do: just making sure you are using the correct helper here... a LOT of people are not, and it's causing a LOT of problems. Here's a perfect example of that which seems, to me, to be related to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414351/mvc-3-html-editorfor-seems-to-cache-old-values-after-ajax-call

Comment: That's rather the opposite of my problem.  I *want* the "cached" values from model state, and they work fine on everything except the collection

Comment: then you don't have a choice but to use either hidden fields or some other method to properly persist the data across... it is indeed a bit of a clumsy workaround, and a cleaner version is to cache information at the service level or through some other means, but the most "state-driven" and "efficient" workaround is through hidden fields. I also wouldn't rely on the other parts that you are saying are working correctly to do so in every situation... tomorrow, those could stop working as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand the question.  Using TempData to persist ModelState during PRG has been around about as long as MVC, it isn't some hack I just made up.  The data is all there, the problem is getting it to display properly.

Comment: Using `TempData` to try and follow a RPG pattern when `ModelState` is invalid is a hack (and refreshing the browser will cause your app to fail). MVC is designed around returning the view when `ModelState` is invalid (not redirecting). If your collection is empty then `EditorFor()` will not attempt to generate any html so the code that checks `ModelState` for the `AttemptedValue` is never even hit.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I suppose you're entitled to your opinion that it's a hack... but it's been recommended as a MVC 'best practice' for years.  The rest of your comment is flat-out incorrect: refreshing the page does not not cause a failure of any kind, and the workaround code I added to the OP is ugly but has been working fine since I made that edit.

Comment: Are you serious. `TempData` only lasts one request (unless you use `.Peek()` or `.Keep()`) so refreshing the browser means its no longer available. And where on earth did you get the idea that _but it's been recommended as a MVC 'best practice' for years_

Answer (score 0):

There are no simple workarounds. You should use the hidden field.