# RenderPartial using inside PartialView in MVC3 ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I am thoroughly confused about how this works:

I have a partial view that is rendered by the controller.  This partial view is rendered via Ajax call and is served by an ActionResult of a controller.  Partial View is strongly typed and is rendered with a model via

```
return this.PartialView("OuterPartialView", modelObject).
```

Inside this partial view, I am rendering another partial view, also strongly typed and bound to the same model, via the `@{ Html.RenderPartial("HiddenVariablesView", Model); }` call that renders a small section of Hidden variables (I use HiddenFor to inject them into the form).

**Issue is**: the hidden input variables are rendered in the HTML as empty/default values of the model - as if the model that was passed was simply created via default constructor.  What's even more strange, is that when I put a breakpoint inside the partial view generation ("HiddenVariablesView" as well as "OuterPartialView") I can see that my Model object is correctly populated.

Would appreciate any advice

**EDIT:** The "OuterPartialView" has a form that submits back to itself (via ajax) and basically replaces itself with a new version of itself inside a div.  It appears that the model for the partial view is reverting back to the model that was originally created when the OuterPartialView was constructed via GET method of the action controller.  Any POST methods of the controller are called during the submits, but the changes to model that are done inside the controller are not reflecting in the generated HTML

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing your issue, but I can verify that having a Partial View render another partial view by passing its own model will not cause the behavior you described. There must be some other issue. Side note: shouldnt it be @{ Html.RenderPartial("HiddenVariablesView", Model); }?

Comment: Thanks the reply. Yes, the RenderPartial syntax you describe is how I'm using it... was typing from memory

Comment: hey can you try @Html.Partial("HiddenVariablesView", Model) P.S are the fields empty when you inspect the elements or are the empty when a form is submitted ?

Comment: Just tried.  Same result... I can also output the result of the @Html.Partial() call to immediate window and see that it generates the HTML with default values.

Comment: In your ajax post where you create the new model... if you add ModelState.Clear(); right before returning your partial view with the new model does that solve your problem?

Comment: ModelState.Clear() fixed the issue! THANK YOU! Why was this needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design the HTML helpers will look at your POST/GET data first, and will only use your model if nothing is found. So if you post a model to your action, create a new model, set it, and then return it, these new model values will not be used by HTML helpers. In order to get around this you could do

```
ModelState.Remove("specificvalue");
```

or nuke the whole model with

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

See [ASP.Net MVC Html.HiddenFor with wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710447/asp-net-mvc-html-hiddenfor-with-wrong-value) for more work arounds.