# BeginForm in ChildAction uses wrong id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There is something simple I don't understand with ChildActions.

I've created a simple View for a model, that loads a child action with a form.
The child action has another model than its parent, with a different `id` property.

`Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)` still outputs the **parents `id`**, although `@Model.id` outputs the correct value!

Can't I reliably use the Helper methods in ChildActions, or is this a known bug?

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Models.HomeModel { id = 1, message = "bugmodel" };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Child(int id)
    {
        var model = new Models.HomeChildModel { id = 100, parentId = id, childMessage = "My Child message" };
        return PartialView(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Child")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
    public ActionResult ChildPost(Models.HomeChildModel model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**Models**

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class HomeChildModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
    public string childMessage { get; set; }
}
```

**Home view**

```
@model ChildActionBug.Models.HomeModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.id)
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.message)

@Html.Action("Child", new { id = Model.id })

**Child view**

@model ChildActionBug.Models.HomeChildModel
<h3>Child here</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.parentId)
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.childMessage)

    <div>Child Model ID: @Model.id</div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

Comment: This might be a good reference for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710447/asp-net-mvc-html-hiddenfor-with-wrong-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer given in the SO question I posted in the comment, you're better off explicitly creating the hidden fields

[ASP.Net MVC Html.HiddenFor with wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710447/asp-net-mvc-html-hiddenfor-with-wrong-value)

> That's normal and it is how HTML helpers work. They first use the
>   value of the POST request and after that the value in the model. This
>   means that even if you modify the value of the model in your
>   controller action if there is the same variable in the POST request
>   your modification will be ignored and the POSTed value will be used.

So instead, hand craft the hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@Model.Id" />
<input type="hidden" name="ParentId" value="@Model.ParentId" />
<input type="hidden" name="ChildMessage" value="@Model.ChildMessage" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already realized the workaround but now I also know why.