# MVC5 view showing incorrect ID after cloning entity and returning with new ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, clone

I'm using the code below to create a new entity and give it a new ID. This works fine all the way up until (and seemingly past) the point of view rendering. If I step thru the code the new entity has the new ID, gets saved to the database, and returned with the ActionResult. As I step through the view rendering process the Model.ID property contains the new ID. Once rendering is complete, if I inspect the page elements the ID field contains the old entity ID.

```
public ActionResult Modify(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    MyEntity entity = db.MyEntities.AsNoTracking().Where(e => e.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    entity.ID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    entity.ParentID = id;

    db.MyEntities.Add(entity);
    db.SaveChanges();

    var _entityDto = Mapper.Map<MyEntity, MyEntityDto>(entity);
    return View(_entityDto);
}
```

In case anyone's wondering why I'm doing this, it's so that I can make changes to existing entities subject to approval (the approval process would replace the original entity with the modified entity).

Has anyone had this happen before? Any thoughts on what might be causing it and/or how I might resolve it?

EDIT: Interestingly enough.. if I change any values within the entity, such as a text field or a date, those new values appear in the editor view, but the ID remains the same. If I save, the original entity gets modified with the new values. If I cancel, the new entity exists and I can edit it normally. The issue appears to occur when cloning and returning a view of the cloned entity in the same action.

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyEntityDto
<div id="modal-content" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            @{
                using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "MyEntities", null,
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        OnBegin = "onBegin(xhr,'MyEntities')",
                        OnSuccess = "onSuccess(data,status,xhr,'MyEntities',successCallback)",
                        OnFailure = "onFailure(xhr,status,error,'MyEntities',failureCallback)",
                        OnComplete = "onComplete(xhr,status,'MyEntities')",
                    },
                    new { @id = "modalForm" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                        <h4>Edit Entity</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ID)
                            <div id="wizard">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                    <li role="presentation" class="active">
                                        <a href="#tab1-Entity" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Entity</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1-Entity">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new
                                                {
                                                    htmlAttributes = new
                                                    {
                                                        @class = "form-control",
                                                        @title = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(model => model.Description, ViewData).Description
                                                    }
                                                })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new
                                                {
                                                    htmlAttributes = new
                                                    {
                                                        @class = "form-control",
                                                        @title = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(model => model.Notes, ViewData).Description
                                                    }
                                                })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                    <div id="modal-footer" class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

generated markup for @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

```
<input name="ID" id="ID" type="hidden" value="574a146b-1198-4e07-a199-701d9f8306aa" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required.">
```

generated markup for @html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)

```
d192454f-e35f-41ef-b781-5a5caf84b603
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup that is generated for both the element having issues and the original element?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning : added markup - see above

Comment: If I add @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID) the correct ID shows up, but @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID) shows the incorrect ID in markup.. see edit

Comment: Can you share us your map method

Comment: Map method is just the default AutoMapper mapping.. no special transformations between the two.. I found my answer in another post. See below..

Comment: Because you model has a property name `id` and your method has a parameter named `id`. The value from your parameter is added to `ModelState` and it is that value which is used by your `HiddenFor()` to render the value (changing the value of it in the method is ignored as explained in the dupe)

Comment: If you are wanting to display a new entity (i.e. with a new `id`) then the correct approach is follow the PRG pattern and redirect to a GET method that displays a new view, not return the current view (albeit you could change the name of the parameter in your method, or clear the value from `ModelState`)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it all depends on how you ask your question. I did a more specific google search and came up with the following post:

[ASP.Net MVC Html.HiddenFor with wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710447/asp-net-mvc-html-hiddenfor-with-wrong-value)

The following change, suggested by that post, did the trick - I added...

```
modelState.Remove("ID");
```

...to my Modify() controller action and it solved the problem.